# Trying to set bitrate of HLS Format segments in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, bitrate, hls

I've tried to set bitrate when converting mp4 into HLS Format in FFMPEG but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ffmpeg -y -i myvideo.mp4 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -map 0 -f segment -hls_segment_size 4000000 -segment_time 6 -segment_format mpegts -b:v 350k -maxrate 350k -bufsize 400k -segment_list myvideo.m3u8 -segment_list_type m3u8 myvideo%d.ts
```

As you can see I tried using -b:v and -maxrate and -bufsize but all the segments came out with the same bitrate as when I don't set the bitrate which is very high. Each segment with about 14 - 16MB. I'm trying to reduce it to at least 6mb per segment

Comment: The bitrate can't be set when using `-codec copy`. For changing the bitrate of the original video/audio stream, we have to re-encode video/audio streams. Using `-codec copy` instructs FFmpeg to keep the original video/audio streams without re-encoding (the technical term is "remuxing"). Note that re-encoding reduces the quality, and also much more computationally heavy compared to remuxing.